# How to remove the 'minimum' and 'maximum' values in a data frame and compute the average in 'R'

Tags: r

[image: Data]

I have a data like this. There are six entries for the code 5005132#2000, in which '0' is the minimum and maximum is '22' and for the code 5008568#2000, there are 7 entries, in which '0' is the minimum and '11' is the maximum. I have to remove these minimum and maximum values related to the particular codes and compute the 'Average' for the particular code.

The avg of 5005132#2000 should be 7.75 and
The avg of  5008568#2000 should be 7.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use data.table. The data.table is like a data.frame but with added fuctionality. You will first need to load the data.table package and convert your data.frame (`df`) to a data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

From there, filter out the values at the extremes for each group using `by`, then get the mean of the remaining values.

```
# Solution: 
df[, 
    # ID rows where value is min/max
    .(Cycle.Time, "drop" = Cycle.Time %in% range(Cycle.Time)), by=Code][
    # Filter to those where value is not mon/max and get mean per Code
    drop==FALSE, mean(Cycle.Time), by=Code]
```

An alternative is to use dplyr

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Code) %>% 
  filter(!Cycle.Time %in% range(Cycle.Time)) %>% 
  summarize(mean(Cycle.Time))
```

And to store that in a data.frame:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Code) %>% 
  filter(!Cycle.Time %in% range(Cycle.Time)) %>% 
  summarize(mean(Cycle.Time)) %>% 
  data.frame -> averages
```

Comment: Hi there rg255, can you solve this using library(dplyr) ?

Comment: Hi, rg255, the data is in excel. I am reading the excel sheet

Comment: dplyr solution provided

Comment: Hi, rg255, I have to save those values in a data frame, i should be able to print as an excel sheet

Comment: use an assignment operator (`<-`, `->` or `=`) - see edit

Comment: please accept the answer if it answers your question

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and time!!! Really appreciate your enthusiasm. Great work, rg255

Comment: Oh Yes, accepting your answer, rg255